# ReactDOM: Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, gatsby, react-dom

I am creating a website with GatsbyJS and React and I am trying to make changes to the DOM. At first I tried to do it with JS, but after research, I found ReactDOM.

I tried it in JS, it worked at first and then it gives me an error:

```
(function() {

const today= new Date();
const hours = today.getHours();
const minute = today.getMinutes()
const element = document.getElementById('pintar');

if (hours >= 0 && hours < 9) {
   element.innerText = 'sleeping'
}else{
   element.innerText = 'Doing something else'
}
})()
```

What I want to do is "write" in the DOM a text, according to a condition (if statement), which is related by the current time.

When I first tried everything worked out, but when I changed the condition, and this is met, the following error appears: Target container is not a DOM element

I'm starting with React, and I'm not able to make changes to the DOM.

I copy my code to see what I must do to be able to make those changes in the DOM:

```
import React from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import Layout from '../components/layout'
import '../styles/index.scss'
import headerStyles from '../styles/header.module.scss'
import aboutStyles from '../styles/about.module.scss'
import { IoIosArrowRoundDown } from "react-icons/io";
import Clock from 'react-digital-clock';

const today= new Date();
const hours = today.getHours();
//const minute = today.getMinutes()
const pintar = document.getElementById('pintar');
const a = 'sleeping'
const b = 'Doing something else'

if (hours >= 0 && hours < 9) {
    ReactDOM.render(a, pintar)
}else{
    ReactDOM.render(b, pintar)
}

const About = () => {

    return(
        <Layout>
            <section className={headerStyles.header_wrapper}>
                <h3 className={headerStyles.header_wrapper_title}>About me</h3>
                <h1 className={headerStyles.header_wrapper_main}>Hey there
                </h1>
            </section>
            <IoIosArrowRoundDown className={headerStyles.header_arrow} />

            <p id='pintar'></p>

            <Clock className={aboutStyles.clock} hour12={false} format={'hh-mm'} />

        </Layout>
    )

}

export default About
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, when using `ReactDom.render` you will be rendering something that is outside of react structure, but in your case, you are trying to render something that is inside the react structure and you shouldn't do that.

If you want to render the text inside `<p id='pintar'></p>` what you should do is

```
const About = () => {

    let pintar = ''

    // you can add any logic here and change pintar
    if (hours >= 0 && hours < 9) {
      pintar = 'something'
    } else {
      pintar = 'otherthing'
    }   

    return(
        <Layout>
            <section className={headerStyles.header_wrapper}>
                <h3 className={headerStyles.header_wrapper_title}>About me</h3>
                <h1 className={headerStyles.header_wrapper_main}>Hey there
                </h1>
            </section>
            <IoIosArrowRoundDown className={headerStyles.header_arrow} />

            // rendering pintar
            <p id='pintar'>{pintar}</p>

            <Clock className={aboutStyles.clock} hour12={false} format={'hh-mm'} />

        </Layout>
    )

}
```

Comment: Thank you Vencovsky, I tried it and worked out. The thing is, I'd like to set more conditions, and show different messages according to what time it is. One option is set multiple <p> with different conditions inside, nut I think it mess. How can I set different conditions (like else if) inside the <p id=pintar></p> ?

Comment: @JFelix before the return, you can add any logic to change the variable and then just render it, check my edit please

Comment: Got it, thank you for your help Vencovsky, really appreciate it!